# Picker View with image

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, image, uipickerview

Im trying to implement a Picker View but instead of text I want it to have images, so the user scrolls the images to select one, for example a country picker with flags instead of text.

Is there a way to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
- (UIView *)viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

in your delegate and datasource class for a custom view in your picker. Just add the image to your UIView.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`UIPickerViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html) and [`UIPickerViewDataSource`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIPickerViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) you can specify the height, and a custom view for each row.